# Formatting Biblatex Bibliography in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I'm having some problems with constructing a bibliography in a beamer document: (1) to the left of each entry is a document symbol/picture; (2) different parts of the entry are in different colours (I'd like them all in black); and (iii) for some reason I cannot get the font size to change.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Adams1998,
        address = {Stanford},
        author = {Adams, Ernest W.},
        file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Adams - 1998 - A Primer of Probability Logic.pdf:pdf},
        publisher = {CSLI Publications},
        title = {{A Primer of Probability Logic}},
        year = {1998}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/Users/James/Documents/MWEs/Beamer-Biblatex MWE.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}

Suppose I cite \citet{Adams1998}.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}\tiny

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This outputs the following bibliography slide:

[image]

If someone could help it would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Regarding (1): `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}` should remove the icons.

Comment: Regarding (2): You can change the color of the elements to your liking by using `\setbeamercolor{>element<}{>color<}` with >element< being `bibliography entry author`, ...

Comment: Regarding (3): Something like `\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\footnotesize}` might help.

Comment: @leandriis Would you like collect your comments here into an answer, so the question can be marked as solved?

Comment: @leandriis Can I bother you about this again? If you don't want to write an answer I will probably collect your comments into a CW answer.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for the kind reminder. I have bundled my comments into an answer.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can use a combination of

`\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}` to remove the bibliography item symbol,

`\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry <...>}{fg=<color>}` to change the color and

`\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry <...>}{size=<font size>}` the font size of the elements:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Adams1998,
        address = {Stanford},
        author = {Adams, Ernest W.},
        file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Adams - 1998 - A Primer of Probability Logic.pdf:pdf},
        publisher = {CSLI Publications},
        title = {{A Primer of Probability Logic}},
        year = {1998}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}

\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}

Suppose I cite \citet{Adams1998}.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]